# How to make power bi work with many to many?

Tags: sql, database, powerbi

I have the following model, where the relation tables create a many to many relationship, as usual.

```
|Table car |      |relation car worker|
|Id car    |1----*|id car             |
|car things|      |id worker          |*-----         
                                             | 
                                             | 
                 |table worker  |            /
                 |id worker     |1----------/
                 |worker things |       \
                                         \_______________ 
                                                         \
|table building |      |relation worker building|         |
|id building    |1----*|id building             |         | 
|building things|      |id worker               |*---------
```

When I load this model in Power Bi, it can build a table visualization (and others) containing one of the following:

- Option 1:

  - Car things
  - Worker things
- Option 2:

  - Worker things
  - Building things

But it totally fails when I try to put in the table visualization something from the edges of the model:

- Car things
- Building things

This is the error:

[image]

What's going on here? Why the error?

Basically I need to see which cars visit which buildings (and do one or two summarizations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new table as if I were doing an inner join in SQL (which works just as expected).

Click "modeling", "create table".

For the formula:

```
NewTable = NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_cars, 
               NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_rel_car_worker, 
                   NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_workers, 
                       NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_rel_worker_building, tb_buildings))))
```

Then I start using everything from this table instead of the others.

---

In order to create metrics that include zero counts grouped by one of the edge tables, I had to leave this table separate:

```
    Partial Table= NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_rel_car_worker, 
                       NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_workers, 
                           NATURALINNERJOIN(tb_rel_worker_building, tb_buildings))))
```

Then in the relationship editor, I added a relation between `Partial Table[id_car]` and `tb_cars[id_car]`.

Now the metrics grouped by car can use the technique of adding `+0` to the DAX formulas to show also cars whose metric sum zero in charts.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can understand from your model.. you need to set your cross filter direction to both rather than single so it can filter back up the tables

Comment: What is a cross filter direction? Where do I change it?

Comment: if you go to manage relationships, then edit. You should see down the bottom right "Cross filter direction". 
This means both 
1. Table A filters Table B and
2. Table B filters Table A

Comment: Tried this, can see the double arrows in the relationship now. Doesn't work.

Comment: Well, when it's about one pair of tables, this solves a lot of unexpected problems (upvote). But when it's about two pairs of tables as in my model, then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you to understand

For example, for 1 from `tableA`, it can relate 1 or 2 from `tableB`, since 1 from Table B can also relate 1 or 2 from `tableC`, so for 1 from `tableA`, it can’t determine whether 1 or 2 from `tableC` should be refer to

```
*----------------------------*
|Table A   Table B   Table C |
*----------------------------*
|   1          1        1,2  |
|   1          2        1,2  |
*----------------------------*
```

You can create a new table with the formula

```
tableName = CROSSJOIN(tableA,tableB,tableC....tableZ)
```

Comment: That's totally not the intention... There are relationships between the tables, I don't want every row x every row. This will result in all cars visit all buildings.